# Blurring algorithm canvas not working JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas

I'm trying to implement a simple blurring algorithm averaging the colors from the surrounding pixels in a 3x3 area.

I loop throught the pixel array, in increments of 4. Then I have a function which takes 6 parameters:

```
r -> red value [0-255] int
g -> green value [0-255] int
b -> blue value [0-255] int
a -> alpha value(opacity) [0-255] int
d -> pixel array [r0,g0,b0,a0,r1,g1,b1,a1,r2... etc] array
i -> current index
```

And I generate 4 new value, new red, new green, new blue and new alpha and return them in an object.

This is the entire code:

```
//canvas setup
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

//create image
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/input.jpg';

var pixels;

img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
}

function action(pixels, callback){
    var newData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);

    for(var i = 0; i < pixels.data.length; i+=4){
        var r = pixels.data[i];
        var g = pixels.data[i+1];
        var b = pixels.data[i+2];
        var a = pixels.data[i+3];

        var channels = callback(r, g, b, a, pixels.data, i);

        newData.data[i] = channels.r;
        newData.data[i+1] = channels.g;
        newData.data[i+2] = channels.b;
        newData.data[i+3] = channels.a;

        pixels.data[i] = channels.r;
        pixels.data[i+1] = channels.g;
        pixels.data[i+2] = channels.b;
        pixels.data[i+3] = channels.a;
    }

    ctx.putImageData(newData, 0, 0);
}

function run(){
    action(pixels, function(r,g,b,a,d,i){

        var nr = (r
            + (d[i - 4] || r)
            + (d[i + 4] || r)
            + (d[i - 4 * width] || r)
            + (d[i + 4 * width] || r)
            + (d[i - 4 * width - 4] || r)
            + (d[i + 4 * width + 4] || r)
            + (d[i - 4 * width + 4] || r)
            + (d[i + 4 * width - 4] || r)
        ) / 9;

        var ng = (g
            + (d[i - 4] || g)
            + (d[i + 4] || g)
            + (d[i - 4 * width] || g)
            + (d[i + 4 * width] || g)
            + (d[i - 4 * width - 4] || g)
            + (d[i + 4 * width + 4] || g)
            + (d[i - 4 * width + 4] || g)
            + (d[i + 4 * width - 4] || g)
        ) / 9;

        var nb = (b
            + (d[i - 4] || b)
            + (d[i + 4] || b)
            + (d[i - 4 * width] || b)
            + (d[i + 4 * width] || b)
            + (d[i - 4 * width - 4] || b)
            + (d[i + 4 * width + 4] || b)
            + (d[i - 4 * width + 4] || b)
            + (d[i + 4 * width - 4] || b)
        ) / 9;

        return {r: nr, g: ng, b: nb, a: 255};
    });
}
```

As you can see, surrounding pixels value are hardcoded.
You can test it here:

https://codepen.io/tyrellrummage/pen/Ewgzzx

If the run button does nothing, reload and try again (some issue with codepen cross-origin). Try hitting the run button several times to increase the passes of the algorithm.

You'll notice that it will completely grayscale the image after 2/3 passes.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing the wrong channels in the callback. And Not sure why you do the `||`

Add `i++` after each colour channel in the callback.

Also the mean value should be the mean of the square of each channels value as the value of each channel is the ~sqrt of the brightness. Not squaring the values will produce a mean that is darker than what it should be.

```
function run(){
    const w = width * 4;
    // the offset index for each pixel excluding the center pixel
    const grid = [-w - 4, -w, -w + 4, -4, 4, w - 4, w, w + 4];

    action(pixels,(r,g,b,a,dat,i) => {
        var idx, count;         
        r *= r;
        g *= g;
        b *= b;
        count = 1;
        for(idx = 0; idx < grid.length; idx ++){
            const off = grid[idx];
            if(i + off >= 0 && i + off < w * height){
                r += dat[i + off] * dat[i + off];
                g += dat[i + 1 + off] * dat[i + 1 + off];
                b += dat[i + 2 + off] * dat[i + 2 + off];
                a += dat[i + 3 + off];
                count ++;
            }
        }
        r = Math.sqrt(r / count);
        g = Math.sqrt(g / count);
        b = Math.sqrt(b / count);
        a = a / count;
        return {r,g,b,a};
     });
}
```

BTW move the line `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";` above the line you set the `img.src` as when the image is in cached it gets loaded before the next line and the anon header does not get attached to the request.